# Speed up android geth sync

Tags: go-ethereum, android

Hi I'm using rinkeby as test node for my mobile app. When I connect to node it need much time for sync mobile client with current head (especially on new accounts). Is there possibility not to download all blocks on mobile?

May be I'm doing wrong, but I can't do such thing as getting balance or making transactions without latest head.

UPD: I'm waiting while client.syncProgress returns not null variable. Then I request balance and get 0 value. But I have eth on the wallet.

Comment: Did you try light mode? It is geared towards thin clients, you do not download blocks directly but it forwards queries to a full node that understand the light protocol.

Answer (score 0):

You may try instructions from this site on how to run a light node:

> A light node synchronizes the blockchain by downloading and verifying only the chain of headers from the genesis block to the current head, without executing any transactions or retrieving any associated state
>   https://www.rinkeby.io/#geth

Comment: I'm looking for light node syncing for Android. I've used android java sample from this site and its very slow. All my first post is about this sample.